# 'unknown provider error' in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I followed the Angular docs to create my Service and saw an error message

`http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector:unpr?p0=$scopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20$users`

This is my code:

```
var angularApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
angularApp.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});

angularApp.service('$users', function($scope, $http, $cookie, $window) {
  // need to instantiate the service
  var newUsersServiceInstance;

  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  $scope.user // = User.get({userId:123});

  $scope.getUser = function(id, s) {
    $scope.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  $scope.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

  // need to return the instance
  return newUsersServiceInstance;

});

angularApp.controller('passwordController', ['$scope', '$users', function($scope, $users) {

  $scope.changePasswordForm = function() {
    $users.changePassword(
      $.param($scope.data),
      function(data, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      function(data, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
          // error callback
          $scope.errors = data.errors;
      })
  }
  $scope.debug = function () {
   console.log($scope);
  }
}]);
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

My new code after taking into account everybody's answer. Same error.

```
var angularApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
angularApp.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});

angularApp.service('$users', function($http, $cookie, $window) {
  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  this.user // = User.get({userId:123});

  this.getUser = function(id, s) {
    this.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  this.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

 return this;

});

angularApp.controller('passwordController', ['$scope', '$users', function($scope, $users) {

  $scope.changePasswordForm = function() {
    $users.changePassword(
      $.param($scope.data),
      function(data, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      function(data, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
          // error callback
          $scope.errors = data.errors;
      })
  }
  $scope.debug = function () {
   console.log($scope);
  }
}]);
```

Even after changing to use factory I see the same errors.

```
var angularApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
angularApp.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});

angularApp.factory('$users', function($resource, $http, $cookie, $window) {
  // need to instantiate the service
  var newUsersServiceInstance = {};

  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  newUsersServiceInstance.user // = User.get({userId:123});

  newUsersServiceInstance.getUser = function(id, s) {
    newUsersServiceInstance.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  newUsersServiceInstance.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

  // need to return the instance
  return newUsersServiceInstance;

});

angularApp.controller('passwordController', ['$scope', '$users', function($scope, $users) {

  $scope.changePasswordForm = function() {
    $users.changePassword(
      $.param($scope.data),
      function(data, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      function(data, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
          // error callback
          $scope.errors = data.errors;
      })
  }
  $scope.debug = function () {
   console.log($scope);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Are you clearing your cache, after all of the update there is no way you can be getting the `$scopeProvider` error, `$scope` is not referenced anymore.

Comment: You're right. It is now$cookieProvider error. Sorry. I have removed the $cookie and $window. It now works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `.service`, the function you pass in is invoked as a constructor function. You should not return an instance, try something like this:

```
angularApp.service('$users', function() {

  this.field1 = "something";

  this.method1 = function(){
  }
  //more fields

});
```

You return an instance only when you use `.factory` method. I don't see the point why you need to inject $scope into service function because service is designed to be a **reusable component**. In your case, you should get rid of $scope. Refactor the code like this:

```
angularApp.factory('$users', function($resource, $http, $cookie, $window) {//Declare $resource dependency
  // need to instantiate the service
  var newUsersServiceInstance;

  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  newUsersServiceInstance.user; // = User.get({userId:123});

  newUsersServiceInstance.getUser = function(id, s) {
    newUsersServiceInstance.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  newUsersServiceInstance.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

  // need to return the instance
  return newUsersServiceInstance;

});
```

You also have to declare dependency with ngResource, ngCookies if you need to inject them into your factory function.

```
var angularApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngResource','ngCookies']);
```

And don't forget to add:

```
 <script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

If you use a CDN, you could add:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js">       </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-cookies.js">       </script>
```

Comment: I have changed based on your answer. I am sticking to `.service`. Same error as before.

Comment: @Kim Stacks: you forgot to declare $resource dependency and ngResource. See updated answer

Comment: @Kim Stacks: in your case, you should use `.factory` instead of `.service`

Comment: Have changed to `.factory` and added ngResource and added the $resource dependency. Same errors. See question above.

Comment: I realized it is because I did not remove $cookie and $window dependency. No more errors.

Comment: @Kim Stacks: yes, you forgot to install cookie module. I missed that

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to write service.

A) use `.factory`

B) use `.service`

If the service uses `$resource`, then inside the module, you need to require `ngResource`, download and add the `angular-resource.js` accordingly.

To use `ngResource`,

`var angularApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngResource']);`

for A)

```
angularApp.factory('$users', function($resource, $http) {
  // need to instantiate the service
  var newUsersServiceInstance = {};

  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  newUsersServiceInstance.user // = User.get({userId:123});

  newUsersServiceInstance.getUser = function(id, s) {
    newUsersServiceInstance.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  newUsersServiceInstance.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

  // need to return the instance
  return newUsersServiceInstance;

});
```

for B)

```
angularApp.service('$users', function($resource, $http) {

  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  this.user // = User.get({userId:123});

  this.getUser = function(id, s) {
    this.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  this.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

});
```

I chose B. Less lines to write.

Comment: I guess the option A should start by `angularApp.factory` instead of `angularApp.service`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Services don't have `$scope`, you can access `$rootScope` if needed but it looks like you just want to return an object with all of the functions you want to use.

```
angularApp.factory('$users', function($http, $cookie, $window) {
  // need to instantiate the service
  var newUsersServiceInstance = {};

  // upper case is resource
  var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
  var MyPassword = $resource('/mypasswords/new');
  // lower case is instance you tend to want the instance
  // to be binded to the controller's scope
  newUsersServiceInstance.user // = User.get({userId:123});

  newUsersServiceInstance.getUser = function(id, s) {
    newUsersServiceInstance.user = User.get({"userId": id}, s, e);
  }

  newUsersServiceInstance.changePassword = function(data, s, e) {
    MyPassword.post(data, s, e);
  }

  // need to return the instance
  return newUsersServiceInstance;

});
```

Comment: I have changed based on your answer. I am sticking to `.service`. Same error as before.

Comment: not really, you are not returning anything with your function.  Note how I am returning the object that contains the functions that will be called later.

Comment: I have added `return this;` Still does not work. Now will try to use `.factory` instead. Update you in a second

Answer (score 3):

You might get rid of `$scope` It doesn't go there :P.

`$scope` is a value used in conjunction with controllers.

I'd recommend making your service something like:

```
angularApp.factory('$users', function($http) {
    var userService = {activeUser:{name:'anonymous'}};
    return angular.extend(userService,
        {
            getUser: function(id){
                return $http.get('/user/'+id).then(function(response){
                           userService.activeUser = response.data;
                           return userService.activeUser;
                       });
            },
            changePassword: function(data,se,e){
                return $http.post(...)
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: like what? Anyway, I have changed based on your answer. `$scope` is removed. Same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

As states in Angular docs: [$injector:unpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) (Unknown Provider)

> Attempting to inject a scope object into anything **that's not a controller** or a directive, for example a service, will throw an Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope error. **This might happen if one mistakenly registers a controller as a service**

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.service('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // This controller throws an unknown provider error because
  // a scope object cannot be injected into a service.
}]);
```